# Java - Stream API: applying reduce() operation to find the Minimum value that meets the requirements

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce

Small question regarding Java and its Stream API, especially the `reduce()` operation.

I have as input some Stream of integers.

The integers go from `-1` **inclusive**, to a positive integer. In the mathematical notation, it would be `[-1,n]`.

***Note*** that the **smallest possible** number is `-1` (minus 1). It cannot be `-2`, `-3`, etc., the smallest is `-1`.

I would like to write a reduce function which does:

*Case A* - if the stream contains numbers from `0` to `n`, basically, **there is no** `-1` in the stream, return the minimum number of the stream.

```
Stream<Integer> casea = Stream.of(2, 0, 4);
```

For above *case A* example, to return `0`.

*Case B* - if the stream contains **only** `-1`, there is nothing else other than `-1`, return `-1`.

```
Stream<Integer> caseb = Stream.of(-1, -1, -1);
```

For above *case B* example, to return -1.

*Case C* - if the stream contains any -1, and any non -1, return the minimum number that is **not** -1.

```
Stream<Integer> casec = Stream.of(-1, 2, 5);
```

For above *case C* example, return `2` (and not `-1`).

I am having trouble crafting this reduce function.

What I have tried:

So far, I tried:

```
.reduce(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer::min);
```

Unfortunately, it is not correct.
It is returning the correct result for case a and b.

However, it will return -1 for the case c, where I would like to return **the smallest non -1 integer**, since it has something other than -1 in the stream.

How can I apply `reduce` operation to meat the requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the smallest element that is different from `-1`, firstly, apply `filter()` to retain only *non-minus-one* elements in the stream and then apply `min()`.

As a default value, which would be returned if the stream appears to be empty, provide `-1`.

```
public static int getSmallestNonMinusOne(List<Integer> list) {
    
    return list.stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .filter(i -> i != -1)
        .min()
        .orElse(-1);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `reduce()` you can re-write the code like this:

```
public static int getSmallestNonMinusOne(List<Integer> list) {
    
    return list.stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .filter(i -> i != -1)
        .reduce(Integer::min)
        .orElse(-1);
}
```

***Note:*** that `min` is basically a specialized form of reduction, and from the perspective of readability the first version is preferred one.

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getSmallestNonMinusOne(List.of(-1, 0, 8)));
    System.out.println(getSmallestNonMinusOne(List.of(-1, -1, -1)));
    System.out.println(getSmallestNonMinusOne(List.of(-1, 2, 5)));
    System.out.println(getSmallestNonMinusOne(List.of()));
}
```

*Output:*

```
0    // -1, 0, 8
-1   // only -1 elements in the source
2    // -1, 2, 5
-1   // source is empty
```

Comment: Upvoting because it is the expected result, but I am looking for a solution using .reduce() if possible. With that said, many thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thank you @Alexander for the clear details!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specifically use the `reduce` operator:

```
numbers.stream().reduce(-1, (submin, element) ->
    (submin == -1 && element != -1) 
    ? element // here, I have seen the first non-minus-one number
    : element != -1 ? Math.min(submin, element) : submin;  // here, I would keep updating the minimum without considering any minus ones
```

It starts with a minus one as the minimum, changes the minimum if it encounters a non-minus-one element, and keeps updating the minimum the normal way, ignoring any next `-1`s too.